# Why isnt my code giving me the prime numbers

Tags: python, numbers

```
import math
prime=True
for num in range(1,1000):
     x=math.sqrt(num)
     x=int(x)
     for i in range(2,x):
        if(num%i==0):
            prime=False
        else:
            print(num)
```

im trying to find the prime numbers but i cant seem to understand why this isnt working. im trying to use the square roots to find the problem

Comment: This is rather badly tagged. Could you at least add your language?

Comment: `for i in range(2,x + 1)`.  Plus, presumably `prime` should be set each time through the loop. You want something more like this, of fthe top of my head: `def isPrime(x):
    return not any(x % i == 0 for i in range(2, int(x ** `0.5) + 1))

Comment: I apologize. It's my first time using stackoverflow ><

Answer (score 3):

you need to test all numbers before printing.

```
 for i in range(2,x):
    if(num%i==0):
        prime=False
        break  # optimisation - see comments
 if prime:
        print(num)
```

also, reset prime to True for each number:

```
for num in range(1,1000):
    prime = True
    x=math.sqrt(num)
```